# Declare list in lua

Tags: lua

How can I declare a list in lua like the following python code and how can I index that list?

List in python:

```
image_list=[];
```

Comment: Have you read any tutorial? Have you at least google it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Lua there are [tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)#As_array).

```
image_list = {}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please read this:
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/

Lua provides the data type **table** which is like the most important and most used thing in Lua above all.

I highly recommend you get yourself some knowledge about Lua's types, syntax and standard libraries befor you continue doing anything else.

There are lots of tutorials and even some free books on Lua.

You create a table using the table constructor `{}`

```
myFirstLuaTable = {}
```

And you index its **values** using **keys**.

You can do things like

```
myFirstLuaTable.x
myFirstLuaTable["hello"]
myFirstLuaTable[1]
```

...